# how to get offsets with specific topic from kafka commands?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka topic `test`

I want to get the following style information

```
[console-consumer-46965,test,2]::[OffsetMetadata[21,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092279434,ExpirationTime 1479178679434]
[console-consumer-46965,test,1]::[OffsetMetadata[21,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092284246,ExpirationTime 1479178684246]
[console-consumer-46965,test,0]::[OffsetMetadata[22,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092284246,ExpirationTime 1479178684246]
[console-consumer-46965,test,2]::[OffsetMetadata[21,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092284246,ExpirationTime 1479178684246]
[console-consumer-46965,test,1]::[OffsetMetadata[21,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092284436,ExpirationTime 1479178684436]
[console-consumer-46965,test,0]::[OffsetMetadata[22,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092284436,ExpirationTime 1479178684436]
[console-consumer-46965,test,2]::[OffsetMetadata[21,NO_METADATA],CommitTime 1479092284436,ExpirationTime 1479178684436]
```

**Questions:

How to get the above log with kafka command?**

My Effort:
I knew the command from older version of kafka is:

```
bin/kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --topic __consumer_offsets --partition 11 \
    --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093,localhost:9094 \
    --formatter "kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadataManager\$OffsetsMessageFormatter"
```

But now my kafka version is 2.5.0

need your help,thanks~!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the highest offset you can run:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell \
    --broker-list :9092 --topic my-topic --partitions 0,1 --time -1
```

Remove `--partitions` to get the offsets for all topic's partitions.